Linear-phase zero-latency IR?
Is it possible to capture an Impulse Response of a linear-phase EQ (talking music software here) and then apply it to a new signal in a way that is both zero latency and phase-accurate?
My idea was to trim the IR audio file's beginning by the same amount of samples of latency that was induced by the linear phase EQ. If that would create phase issues, couldn't we do something to the input signal (that which the IR is being applied to) to counteract that?

welcome, Jason,


Is it possible ... in a way that is both zero latency and phase-accurate?

No. Zero latency + linear phase = zero-phase filter. This type of filter is fundamentally non-causal and you cannot implement it without adding bulk delay, which, of course restores, the initial latency.
It doesn't matter what you do to the input signal, the constraint is fundamental. You can certainly shift signals around to time align them, but again that cannot be done at zero latency. You would need to add delay somewhere.

//"It doesn't matter what you do to the input signal, the constraint is fundamental."// - - - - - - Uhm, the latter statement is true, but the former is not.
